# Get a cumulative git diffs for multiple non-consecutuve commits

Tags: git, github, diff

I'd like to know if there's a way to get a cumulative git diff for multiple non-consecutive commits.

For an example, I can get a what changed in each commit using:

```
git diff 123456^ 123456
```

Where "123456" is a git hash.

I can go this for multiple commits. But I now I want to do multiple diffs and combine the output into one.

For an example,

```
git diff 123456^ 123456
git diff abcdef^ abcdef
```

But combine the diff into one. But "123456" and "abcdef" are not consecutive commits.

**Update:**
Lets say a line in file xyz changed:

```
In commit 123456: from "foo" to "bar"
in commit abcdef: from "bar" to "oof"
```

I just want to see that it changed from "foo" to "oof" after these to commits.

*git diff 123456 abcdef* does not work for me because I don't want to all the changes in between 123456 and abcdef.

I dont want to commit anything; just want to this to review code for security.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure someone has a more clever approach, but you could try to squash all your chosen commits down into one and then do the diff on that one. You could do that by doing `--cherry-pick` with `--no-commit`. Once you have the final result, you can `git diff HEAD` to get the diff of that with your base version (assuming you reset yourself to that spot).

Comment: Thanks for you response, but my requirement is just to see the changes for secure code review purposes. I dont need to commit anything.

Comment: You wouldn't be making a commit. The --no-commit holds that off.

Comment: This is in fact the way to go, with or without the `-n` to do the work in the work-tree rather than as a series of commits.

Comment: I think your method is the closest to what I wanted to do... but i dont think what I really want to do is not possible with just git.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

`git diff <commit-A> <commit-B>` can generate the diff between `A` and `B`, even if `A` and `B` are on different branches or from different repos.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not i'm after. I already know how to do this.

Comment: @DDS Now that you know how to do that, would you mind sharing it here?